# HTML hiding form under text information

Tags: html

I would like to make this form below

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="http://cpanel.gateway245.com/auth" method="post">
    <p class="element">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail">
    </p>

    <p class="element">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
    </p>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

So that when a link is clicked the form shows I have seen some websites with login forms like this is it possible to be done in html under div menu ui?

Comment: what actually you asking really ? be more clear please

Answer (score 0):

Showing/hiding content can't be done in HTML alone - you'll need JavaScript to handle the click event.

This is a rudimentary example to get you on the right track. Many, many, many more examples are on SO already.

```
CSS
 #ttt { display: none; }

HTML
 <a href="#" onclick="show('ttt')">Click to show form</a>
 <form id="ttt"> ... </form>

JavaScript
 function show(target){
   document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
 }
```

Comment: But where would the CSS code go? I am more use to html not the css part

Comment: It's prety essential to web dev. My recommendation is do some studying on the subject and you'll find the answers pretty quickly. A good place to start is [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web)